# Obtaining the IP of the user request

Tags: .net, windows, citrix

My Dotnet windows application is hosted in a citrix server.

I'm using the below lines to get the IP of the client accessing the application.

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0].ToString();
```

But, all I get is ::1.

Is there a way to get the actual IP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the item at index 1 of AddressList array.

Rewritten the code as below got the solution

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[1].ToString();
```